# Python: ping a certain IP without console window and with UI

Tags: python, windows, windows-console

Is there a way for Python to send ping and get results, 1 or 0, without the console popping out? I need the results for UI change in style.

I've been trying `import os` and it still shows the console, as well as `subprocess`.

This is the sample I get from other questions but I can't get the console not to show.

```
import os 
hostname = "google.com" 

response = os.system("ping-c 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:   
    print hostname, 'is up!' 
else:
    print hostname, 'is down!'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ping a site in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)

Comment: `DETACHED_PROCESS = 8;` `response = subprocess.call("ping -n 1 " + hostname, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)`

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! it works! btw how can I + reputation you? Im new to this.

Comment: @malikBrahimi I'm not sure if it is the same. I think it will show the prompt. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/205580).