# Get ping time in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have made a program that tells me if I am connected to the internet or not. Now I want it to ping www.google.com and show me the ping time in ms. I don't want to use any 3rd party software or download anything.

Edit:
My code is:

```
def is_connected():
  try:
    # see if we can resolve the host name -- tells us if there is
    # a DNS listening
    host = socket.gethostbyname(REMOTE_SERVER)
    # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
    # reachable
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    return True
  except:
      pass
  return False
```

The above code just tells me if I am connected to the internet.
What I want is a simple way to show the ping of a website.
This is not a duplicate as it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Where is your code? And what exactly do you want from us? :)

Comment: So now your question is "I have code which does something different entirely, please show me how to do the thing I want to do" which is off-topic as well (but the duplicate answers that, too; you just haven't read the answers properly).

Comment: It exists some Python libs for doing ping. Even if you don't want to use them, they are on Git repos. Did you have a look at their source code?

Comment: @tripleee my question has always been "I have code which does something different entirely, please show me how to do the thing I want to do". Also, the 'duplicate' doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: Then you should clarify what you do want, and how the code you posted attempts to approach that goal. The duplicate has a pure-python implementation of `ping` which creates ICMP packets and times them; if that is not what you want, what *do* you want?  Note that we get a lot of questions where the poster wants to "ping" a "web site" but the terminology doesn't match up. A web site has an IP address and you an ping that, but doing so does not indicate whether the site is actually operational.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ping a site in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ping is **not** the same thing as a HTTP connection! The first is a low level ICMP packet that is used to test connectiviy and find round-trip time mainly on a local network. It is generaly not used on broad internet, because for security reasons it is often blocked by firewall and external routers.

If you want to know the time necessary to establish the connexion to a server, do what you would in real world: look at your watch, do the job, look again at your watch to see elapsed time. In Python it gives

```
#import time
...
def connect_time():
  try:
    # see if we can resolve the host name -- tells us if there is
    # a DNS listening
    host = socket.gethostbyname(REMOTE_SERVER)
    # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
    # reachable
    before = time.clock()      # from Python 3.3 and above use before = time.perf_counter()
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    after = time.clock()      # from Python 3.3 and above use after = time.perf_counter()
    return after - before
  except:
    return -1
```

Comment: When I run that, I get
<function connect_time at 0x00FE84B0>
Also, that isn't exactly accurate as it would give me the time it takes for the command to run.

Comment: @IanStegner : Could you have forgotten parentheses in a function call? And what time do you want exactly?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the parentheses, but now I only get -1. The time that I want is milliseconds.

Comment: @IanStegner -1 means that connection could not be established. The time is a float in seconds, so you should multiply by 1000...

Comment: Where is `socket` defined?

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro: `import socket` It is a module from the standard python library.

Comment: Shouldn't `time` and `socket` be imported in the example code?

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro: the answer is written in the context of the question. The code in the question does not show the imports from the standard library, so the code in my answer does not either.